# How I can I draw a memory map?

Tags: diagrams

[image]

It doesn't need to have all the colors in such, but is there a way to do it?

Comment: You should play with TikZ.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried so far or look around on this site and come up with some code to start with. We are happy to help you with concrete problems you may stumble upon. This requirement has two reasons: 1) this site is not a free-service platform but should rather function as a glossary where specific questions are given specific answers; 2) there are different ways to create such a diagram and it is easier to help you if we know your approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drawing is done with my fingers using a tool named [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor).

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,458); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 458

%Straight Lines [id:da3819310486316536] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 106; green, 135; blue, 28 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (285.47,178.87) -- (285.47,232.8) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da9196171290801862] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 146; green, 194; blue, 240 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (155,178.87) -- (155,198.27) -- (279.47,198.27) -- (279.47,232.8) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8123020966558465] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 58; green, 82; blue, 23 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (488,178.87) -- (488,198.27) -- (291.47,198.27) -- (291.47,231.8) ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp8331577108926491] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 98; green, 98; blue, 98 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 58; green, 82; blue, 23 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (404.47,119.99) .. controls (404.47,111.78) and (411.12,105.13) .. (419.32,105.13) -- (499.61,105.13) .. controls (507.82,105.13) and (514.47,111.78) .. (514.47,119.99) -- (514.47,164.55) .. controls (514.47,172.75) and (507.82,179.4) .. (499.61,179.4) -- (419.32,179.4) .. controls (411.12,179.4) and (404.47,172.75) .. (404.47,164.55) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp9142460310149823] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 98; green, 98; blue, 98 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 146; green, 194; blue, 240 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (100,118.85) .. controls (100,110.65) and (106.65,104) .. (114.85,104) -- (195.15,104) .. controls (203.35,104) and (210,110.65) .. (210,118.85) -- (210,163.41) .. controls (210,171.62) and (203.35,178.27) .. (195.15,178.27) -- (114.85,178.27) .. controls (106.65,178.27) and (100,171.62) .. (100,163.41) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp31833772799392634] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 98; green, 98; blue, 98 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 106; green, 135; blue, 28 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (251,118.85) .. controls (251,110.65) and (257.65,104) .. (265.85,104) -- (346.15,104) .. controls (354.35,104) and (361,110.65) .. (361,118.85) -- (361,163.41) .. controls (361,171.62) and (354.35,178.27) .. (346.15,178.27) -- (265.85,178.27) .. controls (257.65,178.27) and (251,171.62) .. (251,163.41) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp8385696727824026] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 127; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (170.47,104.6) -- (188.47,104.6) -- (188.47,177.27) -- (170.47,177.27) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp3328859475054815] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 127; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (145,105.13) -- (163.47,105.13) -- (163.47,177.13) -- (145,177.13) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp6815758228230662] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 98; green, 98; blue, 98 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 72; green, 125; blue, 174 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (117,247.32) .. controls (117,239.41) and (123.41,233) .. (131.32,233) -- (365.15,233) .. controls (373.06,233) and (379.47,239.41) .. (379.47,247.32) -- (379.47,290.28) .. controls (379.47,298.19) and (373.06,304.6) .. (365.15,304.6) -- (131.32,304.6) .. controls (123.41,304.6) and (117,298.19) .. (117,290.28) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp3550282553763453] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 127; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (275.77,105.13) -- (294.23,105.13) -- (294.23,177.13) -- (275.77,177.13) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp12346436338171785] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 127; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (477.47,104.27) -- (495.47,104.27) -- (495.47,180.27) -- (477.47,180.27) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp4109571698402479] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 127; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (276.5,233.27) -- (295.47,233.27) -- (295.47,304.27) -- (276.5,304.27) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da029596985363378625] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 146; green, 194; blue, 240 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (182,178.87) -- (182,198.27) ;

% Text Node
\draw (110,76.87) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {{\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{0.57,0.76,0.94}{VM RAM}}}};
% Text Node
\draw (260,76.87) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {{\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{0.42,0.53,0.11}{VM RAM}}}};
% Text Node
\draw (420,76.87) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {{\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{0.23,0.32,0.09}{VM RAM}}}};
% Text Node
\draw (161,307.87) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large] [align=left] {{\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont \textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.31,0.31}{Hardware RAM}}}};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that is insane! i didn't knew such thing existed for LaTeX! Thanks so much for your tip!

Comment: The problem with that kind of tool is that you obtain ugly codes. Typically, here styles can simplify things.

Comment: @projetmbc Yes it is true. But matcha solved also complicated problems. I like it.